# PostgreSQL Subscribing and Publishing multi-directional

Tags: postgresql, replication

I have a question that doesn't seem to be answered anywhere. (At least that I can find)

I'm trying to do the following:
I have an HQ Database.
Each agency has X computers with local DBs that must synch between themselves (In the agency) and HQ.

Is this possible with the current logical replication of Postgres?

Here is the scheme of what I was thinking
[image: Network Scheme]

My question is, is this currently possible with PostgreSQL?
I was thinking of the following:

- The Master DB is a publisher and subscribes to each workstation on
  the network.
- Each workstation is a publisher and a subscriber to each workstation on the local network segment AND the master DB.

Is this feasible? Or should I develop my own script to do peer-to-peer synch?
Let me know what you think. Thanks.

Comment: This would be very complicated, and the idea that each workstation has its own database suggests that you haven't quite got the idea of client-server software. Probably a single database is the best solution.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe sadly the clients are not very... open minded...

Comment: Get better clients then. They won't get happy with that, and they will make you unhappy as a consequence.